# Link Link Gets Stuck While Assigning Value

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I am solving the following problem:

5.2 Increment An Arbitrary-Precision Integer

Write a program which takes as input an array of digits encoding a nonnegative decimal integer D and updates the array to represent the integer D+1. For example, if the input is <1,2,9> then you should update the array to <1,3,0>. Your algorithm should work even if its implemented in a language that has finite-precision arithmetic.

My strategy was:

First reverse the array input so it is easier to increment the array and take into account carry numbers.

Store resulting digits in a dynamically allocated array using malloc. And so if the number of digits in result exceeded capacity of input array, the dynamically allocated array could simply extend the memory to include the last carry number using realloc.

Reverse the dynamically allocated array so it is in the right order.

Return a pointer to the first element of the dynamically allocated array.

I am simply trying to make a linked list store an int value:

Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Node.h"

void reverse (int * a, int len)
{
    for ( int i = 0, j = len - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        int temp = a[i];

        a[i] = a[j];

        a[j] = temp;

    }

}

int * inc_arr(int *a, int len)
{

    int result_len = 0;

    reverse(a,len); int * a_end = (a + len - 1);

    *a = *a + 1; int carry = *a/10; *a = *a%10; 

    Node * result = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    Node * result_zero = result;

    result->value = *a; result = result->link; result_len++;

    while (a <= a_end)
    {
        if ( carry != 0)
        {
            result->value = (carry + *a)%10; 

            carry = (carry + *a)/10;
        }

        else
        { result->value = *a; carry = 0;}

        result = result->link; result_len++;

        a++;
    }

    if ( carry != 0)
    { 
        result->value = carry; result_len++;

        result->link = NULL;
    }

    else
    { result = NULL; }

    int a_final[result_len]; int *a_f = a_final;

    while (result_zero != NULL)
    {
        *a_f++ = (result_zero->value);

        result_zero = result_zero->link;
    }

    reverse(a_final,result_len);

    return a_final;

}


int main()
{
    int a[3] = {1,2,9};

    int * b = inc_arr(a,3);
}
```

Yet, at the following code line:

```
result->value = (carry + *a)%10;
```

The debugger demonstrates the computer refuses to move beyond this code 
line no matter how many times I try to step through it using the 
debugger. What is the reason for this? I end up getting a:

fish: './exercise_5-2.o' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Comment: FYI, your reverse function is double swapping your values.  You only want to walk half the list.

Comment: `Node * result = malloc(sizeof(Node));` followed by `result = result->link;` will *not* work as you apparently think it would.

Comment: Also beware that `int a_final[result_len]` is not standard C behavior, but I'm guessing your compiler is allowing it.  Are you compiling with all warnings enabled?  I get at least 2 or 3 when I do that are instructive.

Comment: I think you made a point, I need to make result point to a Node, because it doesn't point to anything yet.

Comment: Also, storing the result in a linked list is not the same as storing in an array.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It's not standard C++, but [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are very much valid C.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, `int a_final[result_len]` is perfectly standard C99.  The array so declared is called a "variable-length array".  The same feature is included in C11, but has been made optional in that version.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, additionally, the OP's `reverse()` function does not double swap, given its loop termination condition of `i < j`.

Comment: @TanveerSalim, I don't really see the point of reversing and then reversing back.  That's a lot of work to avoid simply iterating backward.

Comment: Ok, I conceded on the VLA point.  I thought they were still black magic.  I also missed the `i<j` so I take that back too.  The warnings and Linked list comment though are still valid.  But honestly, there are enough other issues here that I should have just stuck to the original question.

Comment: Yes, I am compiling and executing despite warnings. The following is the single warning generated from this code:                                                                     exercise_5-2.c:72:9: warning: address of stack memory associated with local
      variable 'a_final' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
        return a_final;
               ^~~~~~~
1 warning generated.